# How to echo shell commands as they are executed

Tags: bash, shell, sh, posix, trace

In a shell script, how do I echo all shell commands called and expand any variable names?

For example, given the following line:

```
ls $DIRNAME
```

I would like the script to run the command and display the following

```
ls /full/path/to/some/dir
```

The purpose is to save a log of all shell commands called and their arguments. Is there perhaps a better way of generating such a log?

Comment: See also (duplicate): [How can I print each command before executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750450/how-can-i-print-each-command-before-executing)

Answer (score 1474, accepted):

`set -x` or `set -o xtrace` expands variables and prints a little + sign before the line.

`set -v` or `set -o verbose` does not expand the variables before printing.

Use `set +x` and `set +v` to turn off the above settings.

On the first line of the script, one can put `#!/bin/sh -x` (or `-v`) to have the same effect as `set -x` (or `-v`) later in the script.

The above also works with `/bin/sh`.

See the bash-hackers' wiki on [`set` attributes](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/set#attributes), and on [debugging](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips).

```
$ cat shl
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

DIR=/tmp/so
ls $DIR

$ bash -x shl 
+ DIR=/tmp/so
+ ls /tmp/so
$
```

Comment: If you also want to see which numbered line is being executed see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17805088/1729501

Comment: what if I want to color the command when echoing to differentiate the command and its results output ?

Comment: (The ABS has a long history of being unresponsive to requests that they correct bad-practice examples, to the point of driving longstanding community members to create competing resources; moved links over to the bash-hackers' wiki -- the Wooledge wiki or the [official bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) would also be better resources).

Comment: @LewisChan : you can add a colored static or dynamic prefix, f.e. timestamp, to your commands, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620480/2693875 .

Comment: ...and if you are using iTerm2, @LewisChan, then for non-scripts you can color the commands differently than the outputs with this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252001 .

Comment: @AndreasDietrich Thanks. You'd make my day if you actually found a way to implement my joke question. Preferably with some powerful cli tools and only a few lines of code.

Comment: `bash -x foo.sh` was the crux of what I needed. (Posting as a comment because it wasn't immediately apparent whether that would work without modifying the script itself; it did. )

Comment: `set -o verbose` does nothing for me (Arch Linux where `sh --version` yields `GNU bash, version 5.1.8`)

Comment: The `+ ` prefix can be disabled with `PS4="\000"`. By default this output goes to stderr. To output to stdout, use `BASH_XTRACEFD=1`.

Comment: Note that the bash-hackers' wiki no longer exists.

Answer (score 449):

`set -x` will give you what you want.

Here is an example shell script to demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x #echo on

ls $PWD
```

This expands all variables and prints the full commands before output of the command.

Output:

```
+ ls /home/user/
file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Using the word "verbose" that way doesn't accomplish anything. You can do `set -o verbose` or `set -v` (only "verbose") or `set -o xtrace` or `set -x` (only "xtrace") or `set -xv` (both) or `set -o xtrace -o verbose` (both).

Comment: this works good, but be aware that the "verbose" overwrites $1

Answer (score 136):

I use a function to echo and run the command:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Function to display commands
exe() { echo "\$ $@" ; "$@" ; }

exe echo hello world
```

Which outputs

```
$ echo hello world
hello world
```

For more complicated commands pipes, etc., you can use eval:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Function to display commands
exe() { echo "\$ ${@/eval/}" ; "$@" ; }

exe eval "echo 'Hello, World!' | cut -d ' ' -f1"
```

Which outputs

```
$  echo 'Hello, World!' | cut -d ' ' -f1
Hello
```

Comment: Not many votes for this answer. Is there a reason it's a bad idea? Worked for me, and seems to be exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: This is the best answer if you don't want every command printed. It avoids the `++ set +x` output when turned off, as well as looking cleaner. For just a single statement or two, though, bhassel's answer using a subshell is the most convenient.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Not `set +x`, it affects all commands, which is too much!

Comment: A major downside to this is that the output loses the quoting information. You can't differentiate between `cp "foo bar" baz` and `cp foo "bar baz"`, for example. So it's good for displaying progress information to a user; less so for debugging output or recording reproducible commands. Different use cases.

In `zsh`, you can preserve quoting with the `:q` modifier: `exe() { echo '$' "${@:q}" ; "$@" ; }`

Comment: This does not seem to work with shell builtins, e.g. ```exe foo=bar; echo $foo``` will not work.

Comment: It seems to me a great solution. It can eventually be integrated with a `| tee -a $LOGFILE` to printout do std output and the log file as well.

Comment: So the major downside above is only related to the output right? The actual command formatting for what is actually executed is not affected?

Comment: I love this solution and have been using it for a while. However, it seems to fail at complex commands: e.g. `exe (cut -d ' ' -f9,10 --complement ${folder}/hog_crop_px.txt) | paste - ${folder}/lbp_crop_px.txt > ${folder}/crop_px.tx` gives me `syntax error near unexpected token `cut'` even though it executes perfectly without the exe() command. Any suggestion?

Comment: @penelope you could use `exe eval"(cut -d ' ' -f9,10 --complement ${folder}/hog_crop_px.txt) | paste - ${folder}/lbp_crop_px.txt > ${folder}/crop_px.tx"` ----- OR -----  `exe cut -d ' ' -f9,10 --complement ${folder}/hog_crop_px.txt | paste - ${folder}/lbp_crop_px.txt > ${folder}/crop_px.tx`

Comment: Just modified the program so that `exe eval 'foo=bar; echo $foo'` will now work

Comment: @Soth I am trying your new function, and it seems like it should work okay with `eval`. However, I'm sure I've tried using your original function with and without brackets before I posted here and your second example was not working.

Comment: I don't like this answer.  There are lots of edge cases where what you see is not what you get (especially with whitespace, quotes, escaped characters, variable/expression substitutions, etc), so don't blindly paste the echoed command into a terminal and assume it will run the same way.
Also, the second technique is just a hack, and will strip out other instances of the word `eval` from your command.  So don't expect it to work properly on `exe eval "echo 'eval world'"`!

Comment: a drawback is that you cannot use this exe function in subshell commands like:
`VAR=$(exe echo "hello world"); echo $VAR`
The value of $VAR will be the echoed command plus the result of the command. like: 'echo hello world hello world'

Comment: I have not tested it but I think there is a drawback to it. If your command had something like "echo $RANDOM" where $RANDOM is a function to get a random number in bash. Your echo output and real command will be different.

Comment: No matter what I tried, I could not get the double space after the `$` to be a single space using variable substitution. So instead I used `sed`: `run() { echo "$" "$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's/eval //' )"; "$@"; }`

Comment: The last output is wrong, should be 'Hello,'
Otherwise you should split on comma ','

Answer (score 103):

You can also toggle this for select lines in your script by wrapping them in `set -x` and `set +x`, for example,

```
#!/bin/bash
...
if [[ ! -e $OUT_FILE ]];
then
   echo "grabbing $URL"
   set -x
   curl --fail --noproxy $SERV -s -S $URL -o $OUT_FILE
   set +x
fi
```

Comment: But, script prints `set +x` too

Comment: Tips: We can use `{ set +x; } &> /dev/null` to silence the `set +x` output.

Comment: nice tip @Kjuly

Answer (score 82):

[shuckc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/how-to-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed/13718771#13718771) for echoing select lines has a few downsides: you end up with the following `set +x` command being echoed as well, and you lose the ability to test the exit code with `$?` since it gets overwritten by the `set +x`.

Another option is to run the command in a subshell:

```
echo "getting URL..."
( set -x ; curl -s --fail $URL -o $OUTFILE )

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "curl failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

which will give you output like:

```
getting URL...
+ curl -s --fail http://example.com/missing -o /tmp/example
curl failed
```

This does incur the overhead of creating a new subshell for the command, though.

Comment: Nice way to avoid the `++ set +x` output.

Comment: Even better: replace `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` with `if (set -x; COMMAND)`.

Comment: In my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121256/how-can-i-echo-bash-commands-except-the-very-echo-command) someone recommended this cool solution: https://superuser.com/questions/806599/suppress-execution-trace-for-echo-command/1141026

Answer (score 47):

According to [TLDP](http://tldp.org/guides.html)'s [Bash Guide for Beginners: Chapter 2. Writing and debugging scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html):

> **2.3.1. Debugging on the entire script**
>
> ```
> $ bash -x script1.sh
> ```
>
> ...
>
> There is now a full-fledged debugger for Bash, available at [SourceForge](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/). These debugging features are available in most modern versions of Bash, starting from 3.x.
>
> **2.3.2. Debugging on part(s) of the script**
>
> ```
> set -x            # Activate debugging from here
> w
> set +x            # Stop debugging from here
> ```
>
> ...
>
> *Table 2-1. Overview of set debugging options*

```
    Short  | Long notation | Result
    -------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
    set -f | set -o noglob | Disable file name generation using metacharacters (globbing).
    set -v | set -o verbose| Prints shell input lines as they are read.
    set -x | set -o xtrace | Print command traces before executing command.
```

> ...
>
> Alternatively, these modes can be specified in the script itself, by
>   adding the desired options to the first line shell declaration.
>   Options can be combined, as is usually the case with UNIX commands:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash -xv
> ```

Answer (score 38):

Another option is to put "-x" at the top of your script instead of on the command line:

```
$ cat ./server
#!/bin/bash -x
ssh user@server

$ ./server
+ ssh user@server
user@server's password: ^C
$
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to work exactly the same between `./myScript` and `bash myScript`.  Still a good thing to point out, thanks.

Answer (score 38):

You can **execute** a Bash script in debug mode with the **`-x` option**.

This will echo all the commands.

```
bash -x example_script.sh

# Console output
+ cd /home/user
+ mv text.txt mytext.txt
```

You can also **save the -x option in the script**. Just specify the `-x` option in the shebang.

```
######## example_script.sh ###################
#!/bin/bash -x

cd /home/user
mv text.txt mytext.txt

##############################################

./example_script.sh

# Console output
+ cd /home/user
+ mv text.txt mytext.txt
```

Comment: Also `bash -vx` will do the same but without variable interpolation

Comment: This is nice, but a bit more hardcore than I wanted. It seems to "descend" into all the commands run by my top-level script. I really just wanted the commands of my top-level script to be echoed, not absolutely everything bash runs.

Answer (score 23):

Combining all the answers I found this to be the best, simplest

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644990/8608146
exe(){
    set -x
    "$@"
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
}
# example
exe go generate ./...
```

`{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226038/8608146

If the exit status of the command is needed, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195655/bash-set-x-without-it-being-printed/19226038#comment91517206_19226038)

Use

```bash
{ STATUS=$?; set +x; } 2>/dev/null
```

And use the `$STATUS` later like `exit $STATUS` at the end

A slightly more useful one

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644990/8608146
_exe(){
    [ $1 == on  ] && { set -x; return; } 2>/dev/null
    [ $1 == off ] && { set +x; return; } 2>/dev/null
    echo + "$@"
    "$@"
}
exe(){
    { _exe "$@"; } 2>/dev/null
}

# examples
exe on # turn on same as set -x
echo This command prints with +
echo This too prints with +
exe off # same as set +x
echo This does not

# can also be used for individual commands
exe echo what up!
```

Comment: Great examples. I would add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of both scripts.

Answer (score 22):

Type "bash -x" on the command line before the name of the Bash script. For instance, to execute foo.sh, type:

```
bash -x foo.sh
```

Answer (score 8):

For zsh, echo

```
setopt VERBOSE
```

And for debugging,

```
setopt XTRACE
```

Comment: Thanks! [This is interesting.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions) `verbose` can be in lowercase. To remove it, use `unsetopt` instead of `setopt`. Example: `unsetopt verbose`. PS: This doesn't work in scripts though.

Answer (score 2):

To allow for compound commands to be echoed, I use `eval` plus Soth's `exe` function to echo and run the command. This is useful for piped commands that would otherwise only show none or just the initial part of the piped command.

Without eval:

```
exe() { echo "\$ $@" ; "$@" ; }
exe ls -F | grep *.txt
```

Outputs:

```
$
file.txt
```

With eval:

```
exe() { echo "\$ $@" ; "$@" ; }
exe eval 'ls -F | grep *.txt'
```

Which outputs

```
$ exe eval 'ls -F | grep *.txt'
file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

For `csh` and `tcsh`, you can `set verbose` or `set echo` (or you can even set both, but it may result in some duplication most of the time).

The `verbose` option prints pretty much the exact shell expression that you type.

The `echo` option is more indicative of what will be executed through spawning.

---

http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html#verbose

http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html#echo

---

`Special shell variables`

`verbose
    If set, causes the words of each command to be printed, after history substitution (if any). Set by the -v command line option.`

`echo
    If set, each command with its arguments is echoed just before it is executed. For non-builtin commands all expansions occur before echoing. Builtin commands are echoed before command and filename substitution, because these substitutions are then done selectively. Set by the -x command line option.`

Comment: How do you disable echo/verbose once you set it?

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer of [Soth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23342259/2444948).

It is possible to create a markdown output without highlight (no language given)

```bash
set -x
exe() { echo "\`\$\$  ${@/eval/} \`" ; "$@" ; }
```

## script

```bash
set -x
exe() { echo "\`\$\$  ${@/eval/} \`" ; "$@" ; }
echo
echo -----------------------------------------------------------
echo # Setup
echo Lets take a random keyframe from in.mp4:
echo
exe eval "kfn=20"
echo
echo "kf=\$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_frames -print_format csv in.mp4 | grep 'frame,video,0,1' | head -$kfn | tail -1 | perl -pe 's|frame,video,0,1,.*?,(.*?),.*|\1|') "
exe eval "kf=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_frames -print_format csv in.mp4 | grep 'frame,video,0,1' | head -$kfn | tail -1 | perl -pe 's|frame,video,0,1,.*?,(.*?),.*|\1|') "
echo
echo Lets select keyframe at $kf. Here are the timestamps of the all the frames from in.mp4 around this keyframe.
echo
exe eval "ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_frames -print_format csv in.mp4  | perl -pe 's|frame,video,0,(.*?),.*?,(.*?),.*|\2  \1|' | perl -pe 's|(.*?)  1|\1\tKF|' |  perl -pe 's|(.*?)  0|\1|' |grep -A 5 -B 5 --color $kf"
echo
echo Lets compare 2 methods of split: actual losslesscut 3.53.0 and another one
echo
```

## Output

---

Lets take a random keyframe from in.mp4:

`$$   kfn=20`

kf=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_frames -print_format csv in.mp4 | grep 'frame,video,0,1' | head -20 | tail -1 | perl -pe 's|frame,video,0,1,.*?,(.*?),.*|\1|')

`$$   kf=3.803792`

Lets select keyframe at 3.803792. Here are the timestamps of the all the frames from in.mp4 around this keyframe.

`$$   ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_frames -print_format csv in.mp4  | perl -pe 's|frame,video,0,(.*?),.*?,(.*?),.*|\2  \1|' | perl -pe 's|(.*?)  1|\1\tKF|' |  perl -pe 's|(.*?)  0|\1|' |grep -A 5 -B 5 --color 3.803792`

```
3.720375
3.737083
3.753750
3.770417
3.787125
**3.803792**   KF
3.820500
3.837167
3.853833
3.870542
3.887208
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log only specific commands, rather than every single line, `set -x` is [somewhat difficult to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644990/14637). But you can use this function to print any command, prefixed with `$` :

```bash
function run() {
    echo -n '$'  # Print $ without a newline.
    for arg in "$@"; do
      printf " %q" "$arg"  # Print $arg, properly escaped.
    done
    echo  # Print a newline.
    "$@"
}
```

Usage:

```
run ls /full/path/to/some/dir
```

Using `printf` with the `%q` format specifier makes sure that the output is printed in a way suitable for copying and pasting into a shell, even in the presence of spaces or other special characters. It seems to escape spaces using `\`  rather than adding quotes, but the output does correctly represent what's actually being run.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to control exactly what I want to see:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="ls $PWD"
echo $cmd; eval $cmd

cmd="cat $PWD/whatfille.txt"
echo "-> $cmd"; eval $cmd      #this prefixes to command for better reading
```

The key to expand a variable is to use double quote. Single quote would not expand.

I sometimes use "logger" instead of "echo" to send to /var/log/syslog since they are often run non-interactively.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat exampleScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
name="karthik";
echo $name;

bash -x exampleScript.sh
```

Output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: What are the colour definitions for your terminal (RGB, numerical)?