# How can I print each command before executing?

Tags: bash

What is the best way to set up a Bash script that prints each command before it executes it?

That would be great for debugging purposes.

I already tried this:

```
CMD="./my-command --params >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt"
echo $CMD
`$CMD`
```

It's supposed to print this first:

```
./my-command --params >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

And then execute `./my-command --params`, with the output redirected to the files specified.

Comment: I think you would have better luck if you changed `\`$CMD\`` to `"$CMD"`. When bash encounters `\`$CMD\``, it replaces `$CMD` with the command and you're left with `\`./my-command --params >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt\``. Since this is wrapped in backticks, bash will execute the command, and instead of printing the output to stdout, it will replace the expression including the backticks with the output of the command, and since this ends up in the beginning of a command line, bash will try to interpret the output as a new command, which is not what you want.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye In fact, don't even use the quotes. With quotes, bash tries to interpret the entire string as the name of the command; without quotes bash expands it properly and treats it as a command followed by args, redirects, etc., exactly as it would usually interpret it if you typed it in directly

Comment: Relevant, in particular setting of the `PS4` variable in order to define the prompt displayed as prefix of commands in tracing output: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/

Comment: @KenBellows, that's untrue. Unquoted expansion is **not** the same as evaluation as code: Quotes aren't honored, redirections aren't honored -- all that syntax is treated as literals. The only parsing steps that happen are string splitting and glob expansion. This is the core topic of [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). If you want quotes/redirects/etc to be honored it would be `eval "$CMD"`, but that itself has [serious security risks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), which is why FAQ #50 _doesn't_ suggest `eval` but instead teaches use of arrays and functions.

Answer (score 502, accepted):

```
set -o xtrace
```

or

```
bash -x myscript.sh
```

*This works with standard /bin/sh as well IIRC (it might be a POSIX thing then)*

And remember, there is [**bashdb**](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net) (`bash Shell Debugger, release 4.0-0.4`)

---

To revert to normal, exit the subshell or

```
set +o xtrace
```

Comment: Perfect, here's more information about this (on a page where you may find more useful information as well): [Bash Hackers Wiki: Bash debugging tips - shell debug output](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips#use_shell_debug_output)

Comment: Note also `bash -v` / `set -v` which is slightly different, and slightly less verbose.

Comment: [It is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25).

Comment: Also it may be usefull the kind of "logical brackets": `OPT=$-` to save all the keys, and `set -$OPT` to restore.

Comment: The `xtrace` option works well but in my environment hitting tab to autocomplete results in a dump of completion file contents. Is there a way to turn on without this side effect?

Comment: It doesn't dump the content. It traces the actions it executes to complete. You could disable bash_completion.d while tracing (you will still have filename completion as that's built into bash) @user1330734

Comment: To elaborate on `set -v`, it prints the raw line of Bash, before variable substitution.

Answer (score 177):

`set -x` is fine, but if you do something like:

```
set -x;
command;
set +x;
```

it would result in printing

```
+ command
+ set +x;
```

You can use a subshell to prevent that such as:

```
(set -x; command)
```

which would just print the command.

Comment: subshell is genius, thanks!

Answer (score 126):

The easiest way to do this is to let `bash` do it:

```
set -x
```

Or run it explicitly as `bash -x myscript`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the echoed commands get send to stderr rather than stdout.

Comment: How do you use set x/-x without having the output go to stderr?

Comment: Use `BASH_XTRACEFD=1` to print to stdout. To avoid the `+ ` prefix, use `PS4="\000"`.

Comment: Note that `BASH_XTRACEFD` only works on bash 4.0 or later (meaning it does not work with the default bash shipped with macOS).

Answer (score 43):

`set -x` is fine.

Another way to print each executed command is to use `trap` with `DEBUG`.
Put this line at the beginning of your script :

```
trap 'echo "# $BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
```

You can find a lot of other `trap` usages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D%20DEBUG).

Comment: This is a neat way

Comment: I like this better than -x since you can do something like
trap 'echo "# $(date) $BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
and it's shows time taken to execute each command inside a bash script. 
Thanks!

Comment: Neat trick. For the uninitialized (like myself), use this command to reset trap back to normal mode: ```trap - DEBUG```