# Running curl in a loop results in unexpected output

Tags: bash, curl

In curl, I do something like this to check if a URL is available:

```
$ curl -u admin:secret -s http://test.app.com/doSomething -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n"
200 http://test.app.com/doSomething
```

I have a list of hosts and paths I want to check regularily using a GET request and the output should show me the response status and the url that was called. So, for a set of hosts tests.app.com, a1.app.com, p.app.com and the paths "/doSomething" and "doSomethingElse" I would run the script and expect the following output

```
200 http://test.app.com/doSomething
200 http://test.app.com/doSomethingElse
200 http://a1.app.com/doSomething
404 http://a1.app.com/doSomethingElse
200 http://p.app.com/doSomething
500 http://p.app.com/doSomethingElse
```

This way I can see that the path `doSomethingElse` does not work.

Now my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS=(
        'test.app.com'
        'a1.app.com'
        'p.app.com'
)
PATHS=(
        'doSomething'
        'doSomethingElse'
)

USER=admin
PASS=secret

# fixed parameters
auth_header="-u ${USER}:${PASS}"
out_parms="-w \"%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\\n\""

for h in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
        for p in "${PATHS[@]}"; do
                curl ${auth_header} -s http://${h}/${p} -o /dev/null ${out_parms}
        done
done
```

It produces several curl calls (similar to the example at the top), but when I run this script, the output looks like the following

```
"200"000"200"000"200"000"200"000"200"000"200"000
```

*Note: The "200" seems to be the status code and there are 6 requests in my setup.*

If I add an `echo` before the curl command (`echo curl ${auth_header} ...`), I get a list of commands that I can execute from the command line and which lead to the expected result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Brace expansion (i.e. "{a,b}/{1,2}" -> "a/1 a/2 b/1 b/2") might help you simplify your code.

Comment: Is it possible for you to completely rewrite your question to something like: "If I run `curl ...` I get "200 http://...". If I put the same command in a loop, the output  changes to "....".

Comment: Is it possible to mix the curl parameters  `-o` and `-w`?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I rewrote the question. Thank you for the suggestion. Changing the position of the `-o` and `-w` parameters does not change the output

Comment: I still wonder, whether one can use `-o` and `-w` in the same command, they seem to me to conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting bash to [print out what it's executing for your curl command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31392037/5074609) with

```
(set -x; curl ${auth_header} -s http://${h}/${p} -o /dev/null ${out_parms})
```

the following output is generated:

```
++ curl -u admin:secret -s http://test.app.com/doSomething -o /dev/null -w '"%{http_code}' '%{url_effective}\\n"'
"301"000++ curl -u admin:secret -s http://test.app.com/doSomethingElse -o /dev/null -w '"%{http_code}' '%{url_effective}\\n"'
"301"000++ curl -u admin:secret -s http://a1.app.com/doSomething -o /dev/null -w '"%{http_code}' '%{url_effective}\\n"'
"301"000++ curl -u admin:secret -s http://a1.app.com/doSomethingElse -o /dev/null -w '"%{http_code}' '%{url_effective}\\n"'
"301"000++ curl -u admin:secret -s http://p.app.com/doSomething -o /dev/null -w '"%{http_code}' '%{url_effective}\\n"'
"301"000++ curl -u admin:secret -s http://p.app.com/doSomethingElse -o /dev/null -w '"%{http_code}' '%{url_effective}\\n"'
"301"000
```

Looking at

```
-w '"%{http_code}' '%{url_effective}\\n"'
```

We can see that the curl command isn't being formatted the way you'd like

As answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110201), you should **always put double quotes around variable substitutions**; though, there's no reason to parameterize  out_parms. Putting that definition inline like this:

```
curl ${auth_header} -s http://${h}/${p} -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\n"
```

gave me this output in the format you'd expected.

```
301 http://test.app.com/doSomething
301 http://test.app.com/doSomethingElse
301 http://a1.app.com/doSomething
301 http://a1.app.com/doSomethingElse
301 http://p.app.com/doSomething
301 http://p.app.com/doSomethingElse
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep out_parms, the same output is generated if you change out_parms to

```
out_parms="-w %{http_code} %{url_effective}\n"
```

and put double quotes around it in the curl command

```
curl ${auth_header} -s http://${h}/${p} -o /dev/null "${out_parms}"
```