# How to get notified, if a specific command is run in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a requirement. I need to print a specific message while a unix command is run by any user.
For example, if someone runs cat command or if cat command gets executed on command line. I need a custom message on the terminal.

Comment: I'd consider asking this at [unix.se], as it's less a question about software development and more a question about system configuration and monitoring. (Now, if you'd already decided on an approach, and wanted help with a specific issue encountered during development of a shim program, a tool to parse sysdig output, or another specific software development issue encountered while trying to implement a tool for this purpose, that could well be on-topic here).

Comment: I hope this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750450/bash-print-each-command-before-executing

Comment: @Wellwisher, the OP here wants something that applies across an entire system (across multiple user accounts, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `spydig`:

```
sysdig -c spy_users
```

***Alternative 1***

Execute `w` with `watch`:

```
watch -n,5 w -h
```

- `w` shows you what the users actually do
- `watch` calls a command (`w` in this case) repeatedly in a user-given time interval (0,5 seconds in this case)

***Alternative 2***

Look in the users shell history e.g. `.bash_history`:

```
tail -f /home/userxyz/.bash_history
```

Comment: The `sysdig` approach here is the only one that is not either race-prone or limited to only showing commands started under very specific circumstances. I would suggest showing it first, if retaining the other "options" at all.

Answer (score 0):

Remove cat from your search path and replace it with your wrapper script. Put the original command somewhere else. Make sure you handle exit codes properly.

Comment: You might make this more explicit -- ie. show the actual commands (`mv /usr/bin/cat{,_real}` `cat >/usr/bin/cat <<EOF` `#!/bin/sh` `mail -s "cat was run" admin@wherever </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` `exec /usr/bin/cat_real "$@"` `EOF`, or whatnot).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package "psacct" / "acct"

```
apt-get install acct
or
yum install psacct
```

Enable it using

```
systemctl enable psacct
systemctl start psacct
```

and now you can check everything a user runs on the system.

```
ac user
ac -d user
lastcomm
lastcomm user
```

Also check out "auditd" for more auditing and logging of events.