Problem with Running Python Script When Called Through a Shell Script
I'm writing a school project that uses a Python interface to calculate the symmetric NMF matrix of some data using a C extension. When the interface is called directly through the command board, it works just fine - but when it's called through a tester Shell script it suddenly doesn't work for all but one of its functions (it works for "symnmf"). When I say it doesn't work, I mean the interface isn't even entered (I checked this using prints and nothing was printed even though the interface was called).
I know the tester's not the problem: a friend sent me the same project that he made, and the tester ran his project perfectly.
Here's the Python interface:
import sys
import numpy as np
import symnmf

np.random.seed(0)
def main():
    try:
        k = int(sys.argv[1])
        goal = sys.argv[2]
        file_name = sys.argv[3]
        file = open(file_name)
    except:
        send_error()

    line = file.readline()
    X = []
    while line:
        data_point = []
        str_data_point = line.split(",")
        for str_num in str_data_point:
            data_point.append(float(str_num))
        X.append(data_point)
        line = file.readline()

    n = len(X)

    if k >= n:
        send_error()

    M = [] # Matrix that will be printed
    if goal == "sym":
        try:
            M = symnmf.sym(X)
        except:
            send_error()

    elif goal == "ddg":
        try:
            M = symnmf.ddg(X)
        except:
            send_error()

    elif goal == "norm":
        try:
            M = symnmf.norm(X)
        except:
            send_error()

    elif goal == "symnmf":
        W = []
        try:
            W = symnmf.norm(X)
        except:
            send_error()
        m = np.average(W)
        H = [[0.0 for _ in range(k)] for _ in range(n)]
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(k):
                H[i][j] = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * ((m / k) ** (1/2)))

        M = symnmf.symnmf(H, W, n, k)

    else:
        send_error()

    print_matrix(M, len(M), len(M[0]))


def send_error():
    print("An Error Has Occurred\n")
    exit(1)


def print_matrix(M, n, m):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m-1):
            print("%.4f" % M[i][j], ",", end='', sep='')
        print("%.4f" % M[i][m-1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Here's the C module:
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include "symnmf.h"

double eps = 0.0001;
double beta = 0.5;
int max_iter = 300;


double **getMatrixFromPython(PyObject *p_M, int n, int m) {
    double **M;
    int i, j;

    M = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
    if (!M) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(i < n-1){
            M[i] = (double*)calloc(m, sizeof(double));
            if(!M[i]){
                return NULL;
            }
            for(j=0; j<m; j++){
                M[i][j] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(PyList_GetItem(p_M, i), j));
            }
        }
        else{
            M[i] = (double*)calloc(m+1, sizeof(double));
            if(!M[i]){
                return NULL;
            }
            for(j=0; j<m; j++){
                M[i][j] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(PyList_GetItem(p_M, i), j));
            }
            M[i][m] = NAN;
        }

    }

    return M;
}

PyObject *setMatrixToPython(double **M, int n, int m) {
    PyObject *p_M, *p_vec;
    int i, j;
    p_M = PyList_New(0);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        p_vec = PyList_New(0);
        for(j=0; j<m; j++) {
            PyList_Append(p_vec, Py_BuildValue("d", M[i][j]));
        }
        PyList_Append(p_M, p_vec);
    }
    return p_M;
}

int get_list_size(PyObject *py_list) {
    if (!PyList_Check(py_list)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return PyList_Size(py_list);
}

/* if flag == 0: calculate the ij entry of MxP */
/* if flag == 1, calculate the ij entry of HxH_t, where M=P=H */
/* if flag == 2, calculate the ij entry of HxH_txH, where M=P=H */
double calc_mat_mult_entry(double **M, double **P, int i, int j, int n, int k, int flag){
    double res;
    int m, l;
    res = 0;
    if(flag==0){
        for(l=0; l<n; l++) {
            res += M[i][l] * P[l][j];
        }
    }
    else if(flag==1){
        for(l=0; l<k; l++){
            res += M[i][l]*M[j][l];
        }
    }
    else if(flag==2){
        for(m=0; m<n; m++){
            double MM_t_im;
            MM_t_im = 0;
            for(l=0; l<k; l++){
                MM_t_im += M[i][l] * M[m][l];
            }
            res  += M[m][j] * MM_t_im;
        }
    }

    return res;
}


/* in this program, the squared Forbenius norm is calculated only for H_next-HHt */
double calc_sq_Frobenius_norm(double **H_next, double **H, int n, int k){
    double res;
    int i, j;
    res = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<k; j++){
            res += (H_next[i][j]-H[i][j])*(H_next[i][j]-H[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

static PyObject *py_sym(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    int n, d, i;
    double **X,**A;
    PyObject *p_X, *p_A;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &p_X)){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    n = get_list_size(p_X);
    d = get_list_size((PyList_GetItem(p_X, 0)));
    if(n == -1 || d == -1){
        return NULL;
    }

    X = getMatrixFromPython(p_X, n, d);

    if(!X){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    A = sym(X);
    if(!A){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    p_A = setMatrixToPython(A, n, n);

    /* free all the matrices */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(A[i]);
        free(X[i]);
    }
    free(A);
    free(X);

    return p_A;
}

static PyObject *py_ddg(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    int n, d, i;
    double **X,**D;
    PyObject *p_X, *p_D;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &p_X)){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    n = get_list_size(p_X);
    d = get_list_size((PyList_GetItem(p_X, 0)));
    if(n == -1 || d == -1){
        return NULL;
    }

    X = getMatrixFromPython(p_X, n, d);

    if(!X){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    D = ddg(X);
    if(!D){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    p_D = setMatrixToPython(D, n, n);

    /* free all the matrices */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(D[i]);
        free(X[i]);
    }
    free(D);
    free(X);

    return p_D;
}

static PyObject *py_norm(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    int n, d, i;
    double **X,**W;
    PyObject *p_X, *p_W;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &p_X)){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* get the number of data points and their dimension */
    n = get_list_size(p_X);
    d = get_list_size((PyList_GetItem(p_X, 0)));
    if(n == -1 || d == -1){
        return NULL;
    }

    X = getMatrixFromPython(p_X, n, d);

    if(!X){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    W = norm(X);
    if(!W) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    p_W = setMatrixToPython(W, n, n);

    /* free all the matrices */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(W[i]);
        free(X[i]);
    }
    free(W);
    free(X);

    return p_W;
}

/* the function doesn't create matrices WxH and HxHtxH (that are needed for calculating H_next).
 * instead, it calculates the appropriate entries of WxH and HxHtxH that are needed for
 * calculating every entry in H_next  */
static PyObject *py_symnmf(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    int n, k, i, j, iter;
    double **W, **H, **H_next;
    double WH_ij, HHtH_ij, dist;
    PyObject *p_W, *p_H, *p_H_final;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOii", &p_H, &p_W, &n, &k)){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    W = getMatrixFromPython(p_W, n, n);
    H = getMatrixFromPython(p_H, n, k);

    if(!W || !H){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }

    H_next = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
    if(!H_next){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        H_next[i] = (double*)calloc(k, sizeof(double));
        if(!H_next[i]){
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError, "An Error Has Occurred");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    iter = 0;

    while(iter<max_iter){
        /* set the entries of H_next (through calculating the appropriate entries in WxH and HxHtxH) */
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(j=0; j<k; j++){
                WH_ij = calc_mat_mult_entry(W, H, i, j, n, k, 0);
                HHtH_ij = calc_mat_mult_entry(H, H, i, j, n, k, 2);
                H_next[i][j] = H[i][j]*(1 - beta + beta*(WH_ij/HHtH_ij));
            }
        }

        dist = calc_sq_Frobenius_norm(H_next, H, n, k);
        if(dist<eps){
            break;
        }

        /* set H = H_next */
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(j=0; j<k; j++){
                H[i][j] = H_next[i][j];
            }
        }

        iter++;
    }

    p_H_final = setMatrixToPython(H_next, n, k);

    /* free all the matrices */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(H[i]);
        free(W[i]);
        free(H_next[i]);

    }
    free(H);
    free(W);
    free(H_next);

    return p_H_final;
}

static PyMethodDef symnmf_FunctionsTable[] = {
        {
                "sym", // name exposed to Python
                      (PyCFunction) py_sym, // C wrapper function
                            METH_VARARGS,
                               PyDoc_STR("Calculates similarity matrix.\n\
    Inputs are the matrix.\n\
    Matrix is lists of lists of floats.")
        } , {
                "ddg", // name exposed to Python
                      (PyCFunction) py_ddg, // C wrapper function
                            METH_VARARGS,
                               PyDoc_STR("Calculates diagonal degree matrix.\n\
    Inputs are the matrix.\n\
    Matrix is lists of lists of floats.")
        } , {
                "norm", // name exposed to Python
                      (PyCFunction) py_norm, // C wrapper function
                            METH_VARARGS,
                               PyDoc_STR("Calculates normalized similarity matrix.\n\
    Inputs are the matrix.\n\
    Matrix is lists of lists of floats.")
        } , {
                "symnmf", // name exposed to Python
                      (PyCFunction) py_symnmf, // C wrapper function
                            METH_VARARGS,
                               PyDoc_STR("Executes the symNMF algorithm.\n\
    Inputs are the matrices H and W and their dimensions (n on k and n on n, respectivley).\n\
    Matrices is lists of lists of floats. n and k are integers.")
        } , {
                NULL, NULL, 0, NULL
        }
};

static struct PyModuleDef symnmfModule = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "symnmf",
        NULL,
        -1,
        symnmf_FunctionsTable
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_symnmf(void) {
    PyObject *m;
    m = PyModule_Create(&symnmfModule);
    if(!m) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return m;
}

Here's the setup script:
from setuptools import Extension, setup

module = Extension("symnmf", sources=['symnmfmodule.c', 'symnmf.c'])
setup(name='symnmf',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python wrapper for symNMF algorithm',
      ext_modules=[module])

Here's the header file:
# ifndef CAP_H_
# define CAP_H_

double **sym(double **X);
double **ddg(double **X);
double **norm(double **X);

# endif

And here's the Shell tester script:
#!/bin/bash

# Colors for output
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
BLUE='\033[0;34m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

# Check and install valgrind if not present
install_valgrind() {
    if ! command -v valgrind &> /dev/null; then
        echo -e "${BLUE}Valgrind not found. Installing valgrind...${NC}"
        if [[ -f /etc/os-release ]]; then
            . /etc/os-release
            if [[ "$ID" == "ubuntu" ]]; then
                sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y valgrind
            elif [[ "$ID" == "debian" ]]; then
                sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y valgrind
            else
                echo -e "${RED}Unsupported Linux distribution for automatic valgrind installation.${NC}"
                exit 1
            fi
        elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
            brew install valgrind
        else
            echo -e "${RED}Unsupported OS for automatic valgrind installation.${NC}"
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo -e "${GREEN}Valgrind is already installed.${NC}"
    fi
}

# Install Homebrew on macOS if not present
install_brew() {
    if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]] && ! command -v brew &> /dev/null; then
        echo -e "${BLUE}Homebrew not found. Installing Homebrew...${NC}"
        /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
    fi
}

# Install necessary packages
install_dependencies() {
    if [[ -f /etc/os-release ]]; then
        . /etc/os-release
        if [[ "$ID" == "ubuntu" ]]; then
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python3 python3-pip
        elif [[ "$ID" == "debian" ]]; then
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python3 python3-pip
        else
            echo -e "${RED}Unsupported Linux distribution for automatic dependency installation.${NC}"
            exit 1
        fi
    elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
        install_brew
        brew update
        brew install python
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Unsupported OS for automatic dependency installation.${NC}"
        exit 1
    fi
}


# Paths to the symnmf.py files
current_dir="."
prev_dir="Prev_final_100"
current_symnmf_path="${current_dir}/symnmf.py"
prev_symnmf_path="${prev_dir}/symnmf.py"

# Paths to the symnmf.c files
current_symnmf_c_path="${current_dir}/symnmf"
prev_symnmf_c_path="${prev_dir}/symnmf"

# Function to generate input files with points
generate_input_file() {
    local file_name=$1
    local num_points=$2
    local dimensions=$3

    echo -e "${BLUE}Generating ${YELLOW}$num_points${BLUE} points with ${YELLOW}$dimensions${BLUE} dimensions in ${YELLOW}$file_name${NC}"
    rm -f $file_name
    for ((i=0; i<num_points; i++)); do
        point=""
        for ((j=0; j<dimensions; j++)); do
            point+=$(echo "scale=2; $RANDOM/32768" | bc -l)
            if [ $j -lt $((dimensions - 1)) ]; then
                point+=","
            fi
        done
        echo $point >> $file_name
    done
}

test_non_existing_file_C() {
    local symnmf_path=$1
    local goal=$2
    local file_name="non_existing_file.txt"
    local expected_error="An Error Has Occurred"
    local output=$($symnmf_path $goal $file_name 2>&1)

    if [[ "$output" == *"$expected_error"* ]]; then
        echo -e "${GREEN}Error handling test for non-existing file passed for $symnmf_path.${NC}"
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Error handling test for non-existing file failed for $symnmf_path.${NC}"
        echo -e "${BLUE}Expected error message was not found. Actual output:${NC}\n$output"
    fi

    # Run valgrind to check for memory leaks in C tests in non existing files
    echo -e "${BLUE}Running valgrind for current C test case: ${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${NC}"
    if run_valgrind_c_test $symnmf_path $goal $file_name; then
    echo -e "${GREEN}Valgrind check passed for current C test case '${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${GREEN}'.${NC}\n"
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Valgrind check failed for current C test case '${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${RED}'.${NC}"
    fi  
}

test_non_existing_file_python() {
    local symnmf_path=$1
    local goal=$2
    local k=$3
    local file_name="non_existing_file.txt"
    local expected_error="An Error Has Occurred"
    local output=$(python3 $symnmf_path $k $goal $file_name 2>&1)

    if [[ "$output" == *"$expected_error"* ]]; then
        echo -e "${GREEN}Error handling test for non-existing file passed for $symnmf_path.${NC}"
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Error handling test for non-existing file failed for $symnmf_path.${NC}"
        echo -e "${BLUE}Expected error message was not found. Actual output:${NC}\n$output"
    fi
}

# Expanded test cases (K, goal, file_name, num_points, dimensions)
test_cases=(
"2 sym test_input_small1.txt 5 2"
"2 ddg test_input_small2.txt 5 3"
"2 norm test_input_small3.txt 7 4"
"2 symnmf test_input_small4.txt 6 2"
"2 sym test_input_small5.txt 5 1"
"2 ddg test_input_small6.txt 5 1"
"2 norm test_input_small7.txt 7 1"
"2 symnmf test_input_small8.txt 6 1"
"2 symnmf test_input1.txt 5 3"
"3 ddg test_input2.txt 6 4"
"2 norm test_input3.txt 4 2"
"2 symnmf test_input4.txt 5 3"
"4 sym test_input5.txt 10 3"
"5 ddg test_input6.txt 12 5"
"3 norm test_input7.txt 8 4"
"3 symnmf test_input8.txt 7 3"
"6 sym test_input9.txt 15 5"
"4 ddg test_input10.txt 10 2"
"3 norm test_input11.txt 6 3"
"2 symnmf test_input12.txt 4 2"
"5 sym test_input13.txt 11 4"
"3 ddg test_input14.txt 7 3"
"4 norm test_input15.txt 9 4"
"6 symnmf test_input16.txt 14 5"
"2 sym test_input17.txt 5 2"
"3 ddg test_input18.txt 6 3"
"4 norm test_input19.txt 8 4"
"5 symnmf test_input20.txt 10 5"
"7 sym test_input21.txt 20 6"
"5 ddg test_input22.txt 15 5"
"4 norm test_input23.txt 10 4"
"3 symnmf test_input24.txt 8 3"
"8 sym test_input25.txt 25 7"
"6 ddg test_input26.txt 18 6"
"5 norm test_input27.txt 12 5"
"4 symnmf test_input28.txt 9 4"
"9 sym test_input29.txt 30 8"
"7 ddg test_input30.txt 21 7"
"6 norm test_input31.txt 14 6"
"5 symnmf test_input32.txt 11 5"
"10 sym test_input33.txt 35 9"
"8 ddg test_input34.txt 24 8"
"7 norm test_input35.txt 16 7"
"6 symnmf test_input36.txt 13 6"
)

# Function to run Python test and capture output
run_python_test() {
    local symnmf_path=$1
    local K=$2
    local goal=$3
    local file_name=$4
    python3 $symnmf_path $K $goal $file_name
}

# Function to run C test and capture output
run_c_test() {
    local symnmf_path=$1
    local goal=$2
    local file_name=$3
    $symnmf_path $goal $file_name
}

# Function to run C test with valgrind and capture output
# Function to run C test with valgrind and check for memory leaks
run_valgrind_c_test() {
    local symnmf_path=$1
    local goal=$2
    local file_name=$3
    local valgrind_output

    valgrind_output=$(valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --error-exitcode=1 $symnmf_path $goal $file_name 2>&1)
    echo "$valgrind_output"

    if echo "$valgrind_output" | grep -q "ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors"; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
# Ensure dependencies are installed
install_dependencies
install_valgrind

# Compile the symnmf.py files
echo -e "${BLUE}Compiling current symnmf.py...${NC}"
(cd $current_dir && python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -e "${RED}Compilation failed for current symnmf.py${NC}"
    exit 1
fi

echo -e "${BLUE}Compiling previous symnmf.py...${NC}"
(cd $prev_dir && python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -e "${RED}Compilation failed for previous symnmf.py${NC}"
    exit 1
fi

# Compile the symnmf.c files using make
echo -e "${BLUE}Compiling current symnmf.c...${NC}"
(cd $current_dir && make)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -e "${RED}Compilation failed for current symnmf.c${NC}"
    exit 1
fi

echo -e "${BLUE}Compiling previous symnmf.c...${NC}"
(cd $prev_dir && make)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -e "${RED}Compilation failed for previous symnmf.c${NC}"
    exit 1
fi

# Iterate over test cases
for test_case in "${test_cases[@]}"; do
    read -r K goal file_name num_points dimensions <<< "$test_case"
    
    echo -e "\n${BLUE}Running test case: ${YELLOW}K=$K, goal=$goal, file_name=$file_name${NC}\n"
    
    # Generate input file
    generate_input_file $file_name $num_points $dimensions

    # Ensure K < num_points
    if [ $K -ge $num_points ]; then
        echo -e "${RED}Skipping test case: K ($K) must be less than the number of points ($num_points)${NC}\n"
        continue
    fi

    # Run Python tests and capture output to temporary files
    current_python_output=$(run_python_test $current_symnmf_path $K $goal $file_name)
    prev_python_output=$(run_python_test $prev_symnmf_path $K $goal $file_name)

    # Compare Python outputs
    if [ "$current_python_output" == "$prev_python_output" ]; then
        echo -e "${GREEN}Python test case '${YELLOW}$K $goal $file_name${GREEN}' passed.${NC}\n"
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Python test case '${YELLOW}$K $goal $file_name${RED}' failed.${NC}"
        echo -e "${BLUE}Current Python output:${NC}\n$current_python_output"
        echo -e "${BLUE}Previous Python output:${NC}\n$prev_python_output\n"
    fi

    # Run C tests only for goals sym, ddg, norm
    if [[ "$goal" == "sym" || "$goal" == "ddg" || "$goal" == "norm" ]]; then
        current_c_output=$(run_c_test $current_symnmf_c_path $goal $file_name)
        prev_c_output=$(run_c_test $prev_symnmf_c_path $goal $file_name)

        # Compare C outputs
        if [ "$current_c_output" == "$prev_c_output" ]; then
            echo -e "${GREEN}C test case '${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${GREEN}' passed.${NC}\n"
        else
            echo -e "${RED}C test case '${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${RED}' failed.${NC}"
            echo -e "${BLUE}Current C output:${NC}\n$current_c_output"
            echo -e "${BLUE}Previous C output:${NC}\n$prev_c_output\n"
        fi

        # Run valgrind to check for memory leaks in C tests
        echo -e "${BLUE}Running valgrind for current C test case: ${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${NC}"
        if run_valgrind_c_test $current_symnmf_c_path $goal $file_name; then
            echo -e "${GREEN}Valgrind check passed for current C test case '${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${GREEN}'.${NC}\n"
        else
            echo -e "${RED}Valgrind check failed for current C test case '${YELLOW}$goal $file_name${RED}'.${NC}"
        fi
    fi

    # Inform the user that analysis.py will be run
    echo -e "${BLUE}Running analysis.py for K=$K and input file $file_name...${NC}"

    # Run analysis.py in the current directory
    current_analysis_output=$(python3 ${current_dir}/analysis.py $K $file_name 2>/dev/null)
    
    # Run analysis.py in the previous directory
    prev_analysis_output=$(python3 ${prev_dir}/analysis.py $K $file_name 2>/dev/null)

    # Compare the outputs of analysis.py
    if [ "$current_analysis_output" == "$prev_analysis_output" ]; then
        echo -e "${GREEN}Analysis test case '${YELLOW}$K $file_name${GREEN}' passed.${NC}\n"
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Analysis test case '${YELLOW}$K $file_name${RED}' failed.${NC}"
        echo -e "${BLUE}Current analysis output:${NC}\n$current_analysis_output"
        echo -e "${BLUE}Previous analysis output:${NC}\n$prev_analysis_output\n"
    fi

    # Clean up input file
    rm -f $file_name
done

echo -e "${BLUE}Testing error handling for non-existing files...${NC}"
test_non_existing_file_python $current_symnmf_path 7 "sym"
test_non_existing_file_C $current_symnmf_c_path "sym"
test_non_existing_file_python $current_symnmf_path 7 "ddg"
test_non_existing_file_C $current_symnmf_c_path "ddg"
test_non_existing_file_python $current_symnmf_path 7 "norm"
test_non_existing_file_C $current_symnmf_c_path "norm"
test_non_existing_file_python $current_symnmf_path 7 "symnmf"



# Clean up build directories and .so files
echo -e "${BLUE}Cleaning up build directories and .so files...${NC}"
(cd $current_dir && make clean)
(cd $prev_dir && make clean)
rm -rf ${current_dir}/build ${prev_dir}/build
rm -f ${current_dir}/*.so ${prev_dir}/*.so


"something goes wrong and they fail to communicate" what's the invocation and the error message there exactly?

@MaximilianGerhardt there're no errors: the tester seems to not be able to run the Python program without any clear indication why. It only runs the Python script for the symnmf function. I added the tester script to my original post

There's a lot in that shell script, and with respect to this question it's just garbage. Just show the Python script / code you're calling (that is supposed to use the .so) and its output.

In the end it flows into python3 $symnmf_path $K $goal $file_name. Use set -o xtrace and then run the shell script to see what exactly it executes. When you run the same command on the commandline, it fails? You can also run python with -v for verbosity.

@CristiFati you're right, my question was very messy and  I focused on the wrong part of my code (the connection between Python and C, which doesn't seem to be the real problem). I re-wrote my question, hope it's better now

@MaximilianGerhardt It runs great on the commandline, but doesn't even enter the Python script when it's called through the Shell script. Where should I use the set " -o xtrace " command? Before I run the Shell script (I also run the shell script through the commandline)?

Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750463/5296568

Check [SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve)). The module code is important (if anyone wants to reproduce the problem). Again, the Shell script should be totally removed. The question should contain the code, build command, the Python script (which can be simplified - hardcode the contents (or a simpler version) of the input file inside) using the module and the output.

that script needs to be run through SHELLCHECK !  , add -x for script debug output, maybe a set -e to stop immediately if there's a failure .... (rtfm for details)
