# Bash set -x echo redirects as well as commands

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I am writing a Bash script where I want all commands to be echoed as they occur. I know that I need to use `set -x` and `set +x` to toggle this behaviour off and on, respectively ([SOF post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/in-a-shell-script-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed)). However, it doesn't echo everything, namely, I/O redirects.

For example, let's say I have this very simple Bash script:

```
set -x
./command1 > output1
./command2 arg1 arg2 > output2
```

This will be the output

```
+ ./command1
+ ./command2 arg1 arg2
```

Bash is not echoing my stdout redirect to *output1* and *output2*. Why is this? How can I achieve this behaviour? Perhaps is there a `shopt` option that I must set in the script?

**NOTE:** I also noticed that pipes will not print as expected. For example, if I were to use this command:

```
set -x
./command3 | tee output3
```

I will get this output:

```
+ tee output3
+ ./command3
```

How do I make the commands be echoed exactly in the way they are written instead of having the pipe reordered by the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible with `set -x`. Your only option is to view the current command through a `DEBUG` trap.

```
trap 'printf %s\\n "$BASH_COMMAND" >&2' DEBUG
```

This won't show the precise arguments as `set -x` will. Combining them should give you the full picture, though it's a lot of debug output.

Comment: But what about FreeBSD system? Because I can't do such a trick there due to the absence of DEBUG signal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Neither `set -x` nor the DEBUG trap will provide full information when certain constructs are used.

Examples are:

ex1.sh

```
for i in a b c
do
  echo $i # Where does the output go?
done > outfile # Here!
```

ex2.sh

```
c="this"
case "$c" in
  this) echo sure ;; # Where does the output go?
  that) echo okay ;;
esac > choice # Here!
```

ex3.sh

```
what="up"
while [ "$what" = "up" ]
do
    echo "Going down!" # Where does the output go?
    what="down"
    echo "Newton rulezzz!" > thelaw
done > trying # Here!
```

and many more like these, let alone all kinds of nested variants. I don't know of an easy way to handle these, except to enter into the land of full Bash script parsing, which is a minefield...

EDIT: If Bash-specific features are not required, and backwards compatibility with the Bourne shell will do, the Korn shell (ksh, tested with version 93u+ 2012-08-01) does a bit better on showing information for redirects:

```
$ ksh -x ex1.sh 
+ 1> outfile
+ echo a
+ echo b
+ echo c

$ ksh -x ex2.sh 
+ c=this
+ 1> choice
+ echo sure

$ ksh -x ex3.sh 
+ what=up
+ 1> trying
+ [ up '=' up ]
+ echo 'Going down!'
+ what=down
+ echo 'Newton rulezzz!'
+ 1> thelaw
+ [ down '=' up ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You should rather use `set -v`.

> `-v`  Print shell input lines as they are read.

The output seems to meet your expectation.

```
$ set -v
$ ./command1 > output1
./command1 > output1
sh: ./command1: No such file or directory
$ ./command2 arg1 arg2 > output2
./command2 arg1 arg2 > output2
sh: ./command2: No such file or directory
$ ./command3 | tee output3
./command3 | tee output3
sh: ./command3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and seems to be the best answer to this question. Thanks for this.

Comment: Note that this won't work for more complex bash scripts with functions, because the inputs in those cases are only read once.