# How to redirect echoed shell commands as they sre executed

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

After the question [In a shell script: echo shell commands as they are executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/in-a-shell-script-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed) I wonder how can I redirect the command executed/echoed to a file (or a variable)?

I tried the usual *stdout* redirection, like `ls $HOME > foo.txt`, after setting the bash verbose mode, `set -v`, but only the output of *ls* was redirected.

PS: What I want is to have a function (call it "save_succ_cmdline()") that I could put in front of a (complex) command-line (e.g, `save_succ_cmdline` `grep -m1 "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's/.*://' | cut -d" " -f -3`) so that this function will save the given command-line if it succeeds.

Notice that the `grep -m1 "model name" ...` example above is just to give an example of a command-line with special characters (|,',"). What I expect from such a function "save_succ_cmdline()" is that the actual command (after the function name, `grep -m1 "model name"...`) is executed and the function verifies the exit code (`[$? == 0]`) to decide if the command-line can be save or not. If the actual command has succeeded, the function ("save_succ_cmdline") can save the command-line expression (with the pipes and everything else).

My will is to use the `bash -o verbose` feature to have and (temporarily) save the command-line. But I am not being able to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what `grep -m1 "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's/.*://' | cut -d" " -f -3` is doing with `save_succ_cmdline` function. Can you clarify?

Comment: Right. I edited the question in the hope it is clearer.

Comment: `grep -m1 "model name"` would be run against the command itself rather than the output of entered command?

Answer (score 0):

Your `save_succ_cmdline` function will only see the `grep -m1 "model name" /proc/cpuinfo` part of the command line as the shell will see the pipe itself.

That being said if you just want the grep part then this will do what you want.

```
save_succ_cmdline() {
    "$@" && cmd="$@"
}
```

If you want the whole pipeline then you would need to quote the entire argument to `save_succ_cmdline` and use `eval` on `"$@"` (or similar) and I'm not sure you could make that work for arbitrary quoting.

Comment: Yeah. That's the point. I need to deal with the special chars. If I flag up the verbose mode (`set -v`) I can have the given cmd-line echoed, with all the pipes, quotes, etc.

Comment: The verbose output appears to go to the shell's `stderr` (same place the prompt goes) so you likely can't do much with that.