# Printing executed commands

Tags: shell, unix, fish

How can I print executed commands in fish shell?

I've tried solutions from [In a shell script: echo shell commands as they are executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/in-a-shell-script-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed), but they are not compatible with fish shell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting from fish-3.1.0, `$fish_trace` can be set to enable output similar to Bash’s `set -x`.

For example,

```
set fish_trace 1
```

before commands that should be traced.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately fish doesn't yet have an analog of `set -x` to print commands. [This is the issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/805) requesting it. If you have ideas for what the syntax and output should be, please share them :)

The best answer today is, if you are trying to debug a problem you can invoke fish as `fish -d 3` and it will show some debugging output as it runs.