# How to show commands being executed in fish shell function

Tags: fish

I have a function in fish shell that calls a bunch of commands sequentially.

How do I add the commands that are being executed to the output?

Essentially if I had a bash script doing that I would add `set -x` at the beginning. Is there a way to do that for fish shell functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing executed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151443/printing-executed-commands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69882690/6096851), this feature now exists!

You can set the variable [fish_trace](https://fishshell.com/docs/3.5/language.html#envvar-fish_trace) to a non-empty value to enable echoing of the commands, similar to set -x. Erasing the variable stops the echoing again:

```
Emily@Peach ~> echo hell
hell
Emily@Peach ~> set fish_trace 1
Emily@Peach ~> echo hell
> echo hell
hell
Emily@Peach ~> set -e fish_trace
> set -e fish_trace
Emily@Peach ~> echo hell
hell
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly there's no good way to do this now. You can invoke fish as `fish -d 3` but that's more for debugging output.

Comment: Although I have a tension to accept this answer, but fish shell users should not accept it and settle down for this. Going to github to make an feature request.