# How do I place stdout on edit line?

Tags: bash

This is bash 5. I want the output of a command or pipeline to end up on the edit line.

```
$ perl -E'say "hi"; say "more lines";'
hi
more lines
$ perl -E'say "hi"; say "more lines";' | ???magic-goes-here???
$ hi
> more lines
> █
```

or perhaps

```
$ hi more lines█
```

Comment: Can't you use `xclip` to capture the output, remove the newlines and then press `Shift+Insert` to paste?

Comment: `bash` (or more precisely, Readline) doesn't have this feature. `zsh` does; for example, `print -z foo` puts `foo` in the edit buffer.

Comment: @chepner, the feature must exist, [tag:fzf] uses it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `fzf` is doing its own command-line handling on *top* of the shell. In any case, it's open source: if you believe it does what you want, you can look in the source to see how it does it.

Comment: Something like using eval or `\`your_command_here\`` (e.g. `\`perl -E'say "hi"; say "more lines";'\``)? What more do you want?

Comment: @gmargari, it appears you did not try what you were writing in your suggestion.

Comment: @daxim I'm trying to understand what you want. What I wrote replaces the command executed with its stdout, in edit line. You want to continue editing the stdout (the output of the command) from then on?

Comment: @gmargari, you have the wrong idea. Run `print -z foo` in zsh as chepner says in an earlier comment to see what I mean.

Comment: I closed the older question [Can a bash script prepopulate the prompt with a command to run when it exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188292/can-a-bash-script-prepopulate-the-prompt-with-a-command-to-run-when-it-exits) as a duplicate of this one, insofar as this instance is more clearly asked and has a better answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> expands command substitutions (`$()` and ``` `` ```). It also replaces other kinds of expressions in your command prompt, e.g. aliases, see resources below for more details.

In my experience it is a very useful and little known feature of Bash.

You can use ``` `` ``` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to replace a command line with its output. It doesn't preserve newlines, though. Also be careful with the side effects of anything you expand on your command line prompt. If you expand an `` `rm filename` ``, it will remove `filename` when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

---

### Example:

```sh
$ `perl -E'say "hi"; say "more lines";'`
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

```sh
$ hi more lines
```

---

If the shortcut doesn't work for you, try <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. It has the same effect. You have to do it this way e.g. in the default Mac terminal.

---

### Resources:

- [Gnu.org Bash Reference Manual: 3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
- [Gnu.org Bash Reference Manual: 8.4.8 Some Miscellaneous Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html) - Look for "shell-expand-line (M-C-e)".
- [Gnu.org Bash Reference Manual: 3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)
- [Superuser Stack Exchange: How to expand aliases inline in Bash?](https://superuser.com/a/247781/1059218)