# In a shell script: redirect echo shell commands as they are executed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is an extension to the question [In a shell script: echo shell commands as they are executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/in-a-shell-script-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed).

So we have our command line echo'd either by using `set -v` (for verbose, before expansions), or `set -x` (for xtrace, after expansions); or both `set -vx`. Great.

*My question is: how do we redirect those echo'd lines (to a file, for instance)?*

If I run the following lines,

```
BLA='xyz'
set -v
echo $BLA > bla.log
```

, clearly, `bla.log` will contain '`xyz`', not the echo '`echo $BLA > bla.log`'.

I clearly need a better/depper understanding about the shell to see what is going on here; would appreciate very much a deeper explanation besides the 'howto redirect' solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send the xtrace output to somewhere else than stderr, you can set `BASH_XTRACEFD` to the number of an open file descriptor. E.g. this would direct the xtrace output to a file called `xtrace`:

```
$ exec 19>xtrace; BASH_XTRACEFD=19; set -x
```

(I pulled 19 out of a hat, you could use any fd number, provided it's not used to do something else)

Comment: In `bash` 4.1 or later, you can have the shell pick an unused descriptor for you: `exec {foo}>xtrace; BASH_XTRACEFD=$foo; set -x`. Starting in `bash` 4.3, you can shorten that to `exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>xtrace; set -x`. (Note that 4.1 is needed for `BASH_XTRACEFD` anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

The text printed as a result of `set -x` and `set -v` is being written to stderr.  If you want all output to go to bla.log, just do:

```
exec > bla.log 2>&1
set -v 
echo bla
```