# Bash: highlight command before execution (set -x)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a bash script which executes about 20 commands and for debugging purposes I find myself scrolling through the output a lot. 
Unfortunately bash doesn't tell me which part of the output is part of what command. 
When I use "set -x" in the script it at least prints some information on what it just executed, but I don't really like the output it generates.

For instance, if I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "foo"
if [ "$ASD" == "QWE" ] ; then
    echo "bar"
fi
```

I would like the output to be something like this:

> **echo "foo"**
>   foo
>   **echo "bar"**
>   bar

Or maybe:

> **echo "foo"**
>   foo
>   **if [ "value_of_ASD" == "QWE" ] ; then**
>   **echo "bar"**
>   bar
>   **fi**

Instead of printing the commands in bold, highlighting with a color would also be okay. But I don't just want to have "+" characters in front of the commands and I also don't like the if statements showing up like `'[' value_of_ASD == QWE ']'`.

How can I accomplish that with bash?

At the moment the output looks like this btw:

```
+ echo foo
foo
+ '[' value_of_ASD == QWE ']'
+ echo bar
bar
```

**Edit:**

One idea I had was to write a script that I would source in the very beginning of the main script and then let the sourced script parse the main one. Something like this:

**source_me.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/$(basename $0)"
FORMAT_SET_BOLD='\033[0;1m'
FORMAT_RESET='\033[0m'

cat $SCRIPT_PATH | tail -n "+$START_LINE" | while read line; do
    printf "${FORMAT_SET_BOLD}${line}${FORMAT_RESET}\n"
    eval "${line}"
done

exit 0;
```

**main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
START_LINE=$((LINENO+1)) source ./source_me.sh

echo "Foo"
echo "Bar"
echo "+Hello"
```

The output in that case is:

> **echo "Foo"**
>   Foo
>   **echo "Bar"**
>   Bar
>   **echo "+Hello"**
>   +Hello

But this method will fail if I use more complex code that goes over multiple lines (if statements, loops etc):

```
#!/bin/bash
START_LINE=$((LINENO+1)) source ./source_me.sh

echo "Foo"

if [ "$FOOBAR" == "" ] ; then
    echo "Bar"
fi

echo "+Hello"
```

In this case I get:

> **echo "Foo"**
>   Foo
>
> **if [ "$FOOBAR" == "" ] ; then**
>   ./source_me.sh: eval: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>   **echo "Bar"**
>   Bar
>   **fi**
>   ./source_me.sh: eval: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token ´fi'
>   ./source_me.sh: eval: line 8: ´fi'
>
> **echo "+Hello"**
>   +Hello

Comment: Write another script you can pipe the output to that changes a line beginning with `+` to be bold using your terminal emulator.

Comment: The commands that are being executed often produce output that includes `+` characters. So that's not an option.

Comment: I don't believe there is anyway to do this, besides rolling a script that does what @lurker suggests. If you can interpret the `set -x` output by looking at it, then you can write a script to do the same. It won't be pretty though.

Comment: Your example shows all shell commands as bold, which are the items with a `+`. Can you show an example where that's not what you want and has lines that *start with `+`* that you don't want to be bold?

Comment: As I said my actual script contains about 20 commands. And the ywon't be of any use I gave them to you because they would only work in my environment. That's why I showed a simplified example. If you want a command that outputs a `+` in the beginning of a line, `ssh-keygen` will do it (e.g. `+---[RSA 2048]----+` or just do `echo "++++"`.

Comment: @Forivin I understand completely. It's just that, to my knowledge, there is no way to change the format of the `-x` output (at least no built in way). You could roll something lightweight and pipe it to that, it may not be perfect, but it may help with the `set -x` eye sore like `./yourscript.sh | awk '/^\+/{printf "%c[1;32m %s\n",27, $0} /^[^\+]/{printf "%c[1;30m %s\n",27,$0}'` where it will highlight lines starting with `+` in green and the rest in a lovely gray.

Comment: As @JNevill shows in his example, I'm sure you could come up with a clever way (regex expression) to distinguish lines like `++++` and `+---[RSA...` from `-x` output.

Comment: *Also, there is no guarantee that hacky awk will actually work it's just a terrible example.

Comment: You could always get the `bash` source and hack that. It's available. :)

Comment: @lurker That was going to be my suggestion too. I agree with OP's frustration here though. `set -x` output is ugly and difficult to parse. It would be nice if it was tweakable with a ini/cfg.

Comment: @JNevill Yes, `set -x` output format probably hasn't changed since the shell `-x` option was first invented. lol

Answer (score 10):

I would like to extend [rubo77's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61074650/2693875) with a few examples that I think deserve a separate answer:

## Plain text prefix

So the basic example is to set `PS4` to some plain text, e.g.:

```
PS4="# "; set -x
```

Which will result in:

[image]

## Color & extra line text prefix

But because you can use special characters and ANSI escape codes you can for example add a new line before each new command and print the prefix in a color, e.g.:

```
PS4="\n\033[1;33m>>>\033[0m "; set -x
```

Result:

[image]

## Dynamic color prefix

Finally you can make the command prefix call other programs *with each use*, which you can use  to add a timestamp, e.g.:

```
# yes, there have to be single quotes below, not double!
PS4='\033[1;34m$(date +%H:%M:%S)\033[0m '; set -x
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `+` to a string of your desire by setting `PS4`, e.g.:

```
PS4="# "; set -x
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `set -x` has no innate knowledge of your terminal, which would be required to send the correct characters to create bold or coloured text.

If you can capture all output through a single file handle, you can probably do this with a pipe:

```
$ /path/to/your/script 2>&1 | sed "/^+ /s/.*/$(tput bold)&$(tput sgr0)/"
```

You might want to [`man tput`](http://man.freebsd.org/cgi/tput) for more information about the tool we're using to get bold type.

The viability of this depends on many factors I don't know about your environment. YMMV, may contain nuts.

---

Note:

You might think it was better to capture stderr separately with a line like this:

```
$ /path/to/your/script 2> >(sed "/^+ /s/.*/$(tput bold)&$(tput sgr0)/")
```

Alas, this doesn't behave consistently, because stderr passing through the pipe may not be submitted to the terminal before *subsequent* stdout from the script itself. Note also that this solution, because it uses *process substitution*, is a bashism and is not portable to POSIX.

Comment: But this would affect all lines starting with a `+` character, right? As already mentioned in the comments, this is problematic because some of the commands I use print lines starting with a `+` character.

Comment: Yes, it's obviously a compromise. The sed scripts I proposed in my answer match a plus AND a space at the beginning of the line, but that's a quibble -- the real answer to your question is "Sorry, no, you can't do that." Every other answer (including mine) is a hack. Another option I use frequently is to add debugging output triggered with an option (like `-d`), which includes `$LINENO` or [`${BASH_LINENO[@]}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fLINENO) if available. But that wasn't your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `set -v`.

-v prints out the line the interpreter just read.

-x prints out the post-parsing results of the line that the interpreter just read.

file `x`:

```
set -vx
foo=1
echo $foo
set +vx
```

Executing:

```
$: . x
foo=1
++ foo=1
echo $foo
++ echo 1
1
set +vx
++ set +vx
```