# Why are there not any execve calls in my dtruss trace?

Tags: macos, dtrace, dtruss

I have a script like this:

`script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

clang -v
```

If I do a `dtruss` on it then I would expect to see an `execve` call to `clang`.

```
$ sudo dtruss -f -a -e ./script.sh
```

However, the trace does not contain an `execve`. Instead there is an error:

```
...
 1703/0x16931:       856       4      0 sigaction(0x15, 0x7FFEE882A3B8, 0x7FFEE882A3F8)      = 0 0
 1703/0x16931:       858       4      0 sigaction(0x16, 0x7FFEE882A3C8, 0x7FFEE882A408)      = 0 0
 1703/0x16931:       874       4      0 sigaction(0x2, 0x7FFEE882A3C8, 0x7FFEE882A408)       = 0 0
 1703/0x16931:       881       4      0 sigaction(0x3, 0x7FFEE882A3C8, 0x7FFEE882A408)       = 0 0
 1703/0x16931:       883       4      0 sigaction(0x14, 0x7FFEE882A3C8, 0x7FFEE882A408)      = 0 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2149 (ID 280: syscall::execve:return): invalid address (0x7fc2b5502c30) in action #12 at DIF offset 12
 1703/0x16932:      2873:        0:       0 fork()       = 0 0
 1703/0x16932:      2879     138      5 thread_selfid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 92466 0
 1703/0x16932:      2958       8      0 issetugid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
 1703/0x16932:      2975       8      1 csrctl(0x0, 0x7FFEEE21DC3C, 0x4)         = 0 0
 1703/0x16932:      2985      12      6 csops(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFEEE21E550)      = 0 0
 1703/0x16932:      3100      13      3 shared_region_check_np(0x7FFEEE21DA98, 0x0, 0x0)    
...
```

- What is causing this error?
- How can I get the `execve` command to show so that I can see the program called and its arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the DTrace script that `dtruss` is using internally is accessing an invalid memory address, which is happening while it's trying to trace the `execve` call you're curious about. So basically, `dtruss` (or possibly DTrace itself) appears to have a bug which is preventing you from getting the information you want. Apple hasn't been the best about keeping DTrace and the tools that depend on it working well on macOS, unfortunately :-/.

For Bash / shell scripts in particular, you can make it print every command that it runs by adding `set -x` at the top of your script (more info [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/how-to-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed)).

If you want, you could also try using DTrace directly instead -- this is a pretty simple one-liner (haven't tried running this myself so apologies if there are typos):

```
sudo dtrace -n 'proc:::exec-success /ppid == $target/ { trace(curpsinfo->pr_psargs); }' -c './script.sh'
```

The way this works is:

- `proc:::exec-success`: Trace all [`exec-success`](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-proc.html) events in the system, which fire *in the subprocess* when an `exec*`-family syscall returns successfully.
- `/ppid == $target/`: Filter which means this only fires when the parent process's PID ([`ppid`](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-variables.html)) matches the PID returned for the process started by the `-c` option we passed to the `dtrace` command ([`$target`](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-dtrace1m.html)).
- `{ trace(curpsinfo->pr_psargs); }`: This is the action to take when the event fires and it matches our filter. We simply print (`trace`) the arguments passed to the process, which is stored in the [`curpsinfo`](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-structs.html) variable.

(If that fails with a similar-looking error, it's likely that the bug is in macOS's implementation of `curpsinfo` somewhere.)

Comment: Good answer. The actual cause of the problem here, I believe, is that `dtruss` grabs `execve`'s `arg0` (the `path` pointer) **on entry** to the `execve` system call, then tries to print it as a string pointer **on exit** from the `execve` system call. But since `execve` completely replaces the process's address space, the pointer is no longer valid after the system call. Because pointers are not valid across a successful `execve`, `dtruss` needs (but lacks) a special case for the `execve` system call.

Comment: Ah, sure enough! I always thought it was a compiled program, not a script, so I didn’t know you could read the source. For reference, I also found it online here: https://opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-147/DTTk/dtruss.auto.html.