# docker run output appears out of order

Tags: docker, stdout

I'll go straight to an example:

```
docker run --rm -i alpine /bin/sh -vs <<EOF
echo BEFORE
cat /etc/*elease
echo AFTER
EOF
```

Output:

```
echo BEFORE
cat /etc/*elease
echo AFTER
BEFORE
3.9.3
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.9.3
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.9"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
AFTER
```

Note that commands itself (like `echo BEFORE`) printed by `sh -v` appear before any command output (like `BEFORE`).

I would expect to see

```
echo BEFORE
BEFORE
cat /etc/*elease
3.9.3
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.9.3
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.9"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
echo AFTER
AFTER
```

I tried using `stdbuf` and `script` as for example described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe), but to no avail.

I don't think I am the only one who has this problem.  So I wonder

- What is the cause of such mixed up output?
- Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: [POSIX.1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) just says "the shell shall write its input to standard error as it is read", so this reads to me as though the shell is reading all of its input before it does anything.  That seems like a reasonable implementation choice especially for small inputs.  Is there a specific thing in your application that depends on this behavior, and can you include its source code in the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze, It indeed seems that sh and bash do not guarantee that input line will be printed right before the command output. However, using -v or -x option (which suffers from the same problem) is often recommended:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/how-to-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed

Comment: >  Is there a specific thing in your application that depends on this behavior?
 
No, not at all. I asked this question mainly out of curiosity. I was just dumping some information from a docker image (like /etc/*elease, python version, openssl version etc.) and came across this behavior.

Comment: @DavidMaze, With the help of your link I realized that it was stdout and stderr which mixed up. The problem can be solved by redirecting stdout to stderr with `exec 1>&2` (put it before the other commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by redirecting stdout to stderr:

```
docker run --rm -i alpine /bin/sh -vs <<EOF
exec 1>&2
echo BEFORE
cat /etc/*elease
echo AFTER
EOF
```