# Is it possible to print all the commands when they are executed in Bash?

Tags: bash

From [How to echo shell commands as they are executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/how-to-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed) I've learned how to use `set -v` to print commands when they are executed. It works well if `set -v` is added at the beginning of `foo.sh` or `bash -v foo.sh` is run. However, if `foo.sh` invokes `bar.sh` by `bash bar.sh` or simply `./bar.sh`, the commands in `bar.sh` are not printed. Is there a global switch that enables all the commands and functions, through all invoked scripts, to be printed when they are executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a global switch that enables all the commands and functions, through all invoked scripts, to be printed when they are executed?

Yes, [`BASH_ENV`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fENV) can be used for that. The manual describes it as follows.

> If this variable is set when Bash is invoked to execute a shell script, its value is expanded and used as the name of a startup file to read before executing the script.

So, you can just put `set -v` in a file and assign its path to `BASH_ENV` while invoking the first script. For example:

```
$ cat env.sh
set -v
$
$ cat foo
#!/bin/bash
true
./bar
$
$ cat bar
#!/bin/bash
false
```

```
$ BASH_ENV=./env.sh ./foo
#!/bin/bash
true
./bar
#!/bin/bash
false
```

Alternatively, to do this without having to create an extra file, you can start the script with a fabricated [`SHELLOPTS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-SHELLOPTS) value

```
# too long, and might require adjustments for future versions
env SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:verbose ./foo
```

or, enable verboseness by the `set` command or by adding `-v` to the shebang and export `SHELLOPTS` within the first script.

```
set -v
# exports all options, not only `verbose'
export SHELLOPTS
# the rest of the script
```