# print bash script comments when bash is executed

Tags: bash, shell

Assuming I have a bash script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Comment 1
echo "Hello world"

# Comment 2
echo "Hi there"
```

I know after making the bash script executable and running it, only the `echo` commands would show as output.

I'm wondering if there's a way to print the comments on execution. That is, I want the output to look like:

```
Comment 1
Hello world

Comment 2
Hi there
```

Edit:

Even after 2 years, I keep getting linked back to this question.

After more experience, I would like to admit that I don't even know why I expected this to have an answer.
Comments are a communication tool meant to provide developers more understanding about a given piece of code.

Since I can't delete it because StackOverflow prevents me from doing so, here's the response.

No. No trivial, inbuilt solution exists at this time to the question "Can you print the comments in a bash script, whiles running the same script?"

You can however use the [set builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html), specifically `set -v`, to print out bash commands in a script, as they're being executed.

Comment: Why not just replace the `#` with `echo` ? Won't be possible to print the comments unless you write a wrapper the does something like `sed 's/^#/echo /'` and then runs the modified script

Comment: The purpose of printing the comments is not very clear at all, if you want to print the comments just to check the code flow just print them anyway, or if you want something like comment detection, you will need some external tool or script as suggested by @git-bruh

Comment: @razor_chk : The idea of having comments to be printed, sounds bizarre to me. There are several commands available for printing information (`echo`, `printf` and others).  One idea to consider is to use the `:`  command to provide the comment, i.e. `:  Comment1`. If you are running your code with `-x` turned on, you see these "dummy comments"; without `-x`, you don't see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common arrangement is to have various logging levels set up, and then emit different amounts of logging depending on the logging level.

```
debug () { ${debug-:} "$0: $@" >&2; }
info () {  ${info-:}  "$0: $@" >&2; }
warn () {  ${warn-:}  "$0: $@" >&2; }
error () { ${error-:} "$0: $@" >&2; }

case $1 in
  --debug) debug=echo; info=echo;  warn=echo;  error=1;;
  --info)  info=echo;  warn=echo;  error=1;;
  --warn)  warn=echo;  error=echo;;
  --error) error=echo;;
  -*) echo "$0: unknown option '$1' -- aborting" >&2
      exit 127;;
esac
shift

debug here we go
info starting
echo "Hello world"
warn the end is nigh
echo "Hi there"
error we die here
exit 42
```

This is just a dead simple demo; you would probably want for it to be somewhat more secure and versatile, and have sensible default like running with `--warn` (which implies `--error`) if no level is explicitly specified.

The "comments" are no longer comments, and the output goes to standard error in this implementation; but as you can see, this also lets you put in "comments" which are actually useful when you are debugging, not just while reading the code.

You can make the commands (`debug`, `warn` etc) look more like comments by renaming them, perhaps to `_dbg_`, `_warn_` etc.

Answer (score -1):

> if there's a way to print the comments on execution

No, there is no way.

> **a way**

Modify bash source and modify langauge parser to parse `#` characters to work as `; echo`.

In trivially simple cases that do not need a real blown parser, you could replace all `#` in the source file by `echo` and run it then. Like `sed 's/#/echo/' test.sh | bash -s`.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what you want but if you set the shebang to `#!/bin/sh -v` it will print out *both* the comments and the commands in the script

Additional Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853811/10359765

Comment: **`-x` does NOT show comments**; it shows only _executed commands_ which does not include comments. `-v` shows all input (comments, executed and unexecuted commands). Your link is only about displaying commands, where both `-x -v` (can) work, not comments where `-x` does not work.

Comment: Removed reference to `-x`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -******************-
echo -** Any Comment  **-
echo -******************-

ls -la # Or any command!
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35366638)

Comment: @HeinrichsupportsMonica: This doesn’t appear to be a new question to me. It very much seems like a proposed answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Sorry, this was an automatically generated comment from reviewing. The problem with the above post: it answers a (trivial) question (i.e. "how do I write a comment") that is only partially related to the original question. As such, I flagged it down as noise.

Comment: @Heinrich supports Monica
Sorry, but I just saw the Question many times online and wanted to help with an easy answer! never gonna answer an old Question again. Sorry