# ZSH function parameters conundrum

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

This is being done from the command line of macOS 14 (Sonoma).

Can someone explain why a parameter doesn't seem to be processed correctly in the following function.

First, note that the following works fine (called directly from the command lilne), so it's not a keychain problem:

```
# [1] succeeds
codesign -f -vvvv --strict --deep --timestamp -s "Developer ID Application: My Company Inc. (123456)" --options runtime "/MyFolder/MyFile.dylib"
```

I can also call it from a function if I hard-code the "-s" argument in the function:

```
# [2] succeeds
function myFunc()
{  codesign ${1} -s "Developer ID Application: My Company Inc. (123456)" ${2}
}
myFunc "-f -vvvv --strict --verbose --deep --timestamp --options runtime" "/MyFolder/MyFile.dylib"
```

However, if I include the "-s" argument as a parameter, I get an error "Developer: no identity found":

```
#[3] error: "Developer: no identity found
function myFunc()
{  codesign ${1}  ${2}
   echo {1} = "${1}"
}
myFunc "-f -vvvv --strict --verbose --deep --timestamp -s \"Developer ID Application: My Company Inc. (123456)\" --options runtime" "/MyFolder/MyFile.dylib"
```

It's not a question of a keychain issue, because the `codesign` works in cases [1] and [2].

The result of the `echo` indicates that the parameter seems to be passed OK:

```
{1} = -f -vvvv --strict --verbose --deep --timestamp -s "Developer ID Application: My Company Inc. (123456)" --options runtime
```

I've tried backticks, escaping blanks, nada works.

Any ideas? BTW I need this because there are many files that need to be signed & verified, I'm trying to cut down on duplication.

Comment: A Mac? Sure you're using bash and not zsh?

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes before expanding variables, parameters, etc; that means if you put quotes or escapes in a variable or parameter, by the time they're part of the command it's too late for them to do anything useful. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948) (but ignore recommendations to use `eval` -- it's a massive bug magnet) and [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: BTW, note that `function funcname() {` merges the legacy ksh syntax `function funcname {` and the standardized POSIX syntax `funcname() {` in a way that's incompatible with **both** legacy ksh and POSIX. Personally, I suggest the latter, as it's actually part of a formal standard as opposed to something provided for backwards compatibility with pre-standard shells.

Comment: For the "why doesn't this work?", though, I really do recommend the BashFAQ #50 link in Gordon's comment above. And [don't trust `echo` for anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), [ever](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo); there's a reason [the standard way to trace shell scripts is `set -x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/how-to-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed).

Comment: @Shawn Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, I'm new at this. I'm using Terminal.

Comment: The terminal is just the display layer -- the part that reads input and writes output. You can run any kind of shell (or other program that uses stdin/stdout/stderr or a TTY to read input and write output) you want inside a terminal, so it could be bash _or_ zsh depending on how your account is configured; but on new versions of MacOS, zsh is default (because Apple doesn't agree to the license modern versions of bash are shipped with, and instead uses an ancient one that's more than a decade out-of-date).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see I'm using zsh, I just got an error message "zsh: no matches found:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to put multiple arguments into a string in Bash is generally not a good idea.  Sometimes the only way to make it work is to use `eval`, and that often just gives you more problems (some of which may be very unobvious).  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

In this case I'd avoid the problem by defining the (Bash) function like this:

```
function myFunc
{
    codesign "${@:2}" "$1"
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
myFunc "/MyFolder/MyFile.dylib" -f -vvvv --strict --deep --timestamp -s "Developer ID Application: My Company Inc. (123456)" --options runtime
```

I.e. put the path of the file to be signed as the first argument and the arguments to `codesign` as the following, all separate, arguments.  Any arguments that work with `codesign` itself are guaranteed to work when provided as arguments (2 and following) to `myFunc`.

Note that if the intention in using a function like this is to make it easy to use different sets of options with `codesign` for different files, then it is important to keep   lists of options in arrays instead of strings.  This code demonstrates how to use an array to build up the full list of options in stages before calling the function:

```
codesign_opts=( -f -vvvv --strict --deep --timestamp )
codesign_opts+=( -s "Developer ID Application: My Company Inc. (123456)" )
codesign_opts+=( --options runtime )
myFunc "/MyFolder/MyFile.dylib" "${codesign_opts[@]}"
```

Comment: One could also use `myFunc() { local firstArg >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:; firstArg=$1; shift; codesign "$@" "$firstArg"; }` -- they're both perfectly fine answers when using bash, but the suggestion in this comment also works with all sh-compatible shells (ash, dash, etc -- though it leaks firstArg to global scope on shells that don't support `local`).

Comment: @pjh Looks like it's working! Brilliant! Thanks to all of you.  What arcana. :o)

Comment: @Pierre, "arcana" is a good description of this stuff.  It's a weird relic of the 1980s.  Given a choice between learning shell (any of them) and Python, learn Python.  (Some of us persist with shell because of sunk cost.)  If you have to use shell then consider using [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.  It can detect many common, and some not so common, problems in shell code.