Running ef core migrations in linux
I am trying to run ef core Migrations in Ubuntu 24.01. I added the dotnet directory to my path and the path of root. I am getting this error not sure why:
dotnet ef database update --project AuthenticationService --startup-project AuthenticationService
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
Process completed with exit code 1.


That's a generic error from bash. You could probably debug what it's trying to do via something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853811/4139809.

So @JeremyLakeman that seems like something specific to dotnet I am not sure it is a generic bash error. Any other suggestions?

I found the answer. I had to add the "$Home/dotnet/tools" to the path.
